# What does 'AP’s health' mean in context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does 'AP’s health' mean. AP above mentioned as The Associated Press (AP), that is - to support 'the Associated Press's health'?

> Doudna receives money from the Howard Hughes Medical Institute, which
>   supports the **AP’s health** and science reporting.

VOA article: Gene-edited Babies Debate Continues

Comment: It isn't *"the AP's health"*.  It's *"the heath and sciences reporting"* bureau of the AP.

Answer (score 2):

The key phrase is "health and science" rather than "AP's health". From the context, the Associated Press produces content related to health and science, which the article is calling "health and science reporting." So, from the context, the author is disclosing a possible conflict of interest: Someone receives money from the Howard Hughes Medical Institute in the same area as the article (it's in the area of health-and-science reporting).